# duktape reference counter and finalizer C/C++

Tags: javascript, c++, count, reference, duktape

I'm binding my C++ objects by using duktape and I would like to automatically delete the instances when they are not used anymore. I've tried to set a finalizer to these objects but for some reason the finalizer gets called only when the context is destroyed, which is fine for global objects but for situations like these it is not:

```
function foo()
{
    var myobject = new MyObject();
    // some code
    // dtor for MyObject called
}
```

There's no need to keep the instance for MyObject once the foo function is over, but for some reason no finalizer is called. As far as I know duktape has some kind of reference counting system so there's should be a way to understand when the object reference goes to zero (ergo my object can finally be deleted from memory), but how? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Very likely you have a reference to these objects somewhere which keeps them from being gc'ed. You should double check where you keep references.

Comment: There is no guarantee that `myobject` will get finalized at the end of function scope. Did you try forcing GC pass with [`duk_gc()`](http://duktape.org/api.html#duk_gc) or [`Duktape.gc()`](http://duktape.org/guide.html#builtin-duktape-gc)?